# Firefox Extension port to emit from main.js

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

I am building a firefox extension and trying to communicate between main.js and contentScriptFile. Basically what i want in when a tab is closed call a function in contentScriptFile injected in all other open tabs. The code i am currently using with port doesn't seems to work

Main.js

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.on('close', function(tab){

if(tab.url.indexOf('example.com/url2') > -1)
{
for (let tab of tabs)
{
  tab.attach({}).port.emit("doCORN", 'eg1');
}
}
else if(tab.url.indexOf('example.com/url1') > -1)
{
for (let tab of tabs)
{
  tab.attach({}).port.emit("doCORN", 'eg2');
}
}
});
```

Contentscriptfile

```
self.port.on("doCORN", function(msg) {
console.log(msg)
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work. So, anybody have an idea?

Comment: How is the content script attached? If you attach the script via the tab.attach() call you show in your code, your code will work. If you attach the content script via a pageMod, it won't because the worker instances you're creating here won't know about other content scripts.

Comment: @canuckistani Thanks. I had attached using Pagemod. Fixed the issue. Had to keep track of all workers and called port of the workers. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah - read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#Content_script_to_content_script) to understand the limitations of communicating between content scripts.